# Problems with Prettier config in vscode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, prettier

I have a standard Angular app and am trying to disable trailing commas in *Prettier*. So I go into vscode settings (both user and workspace) and set trailing commas to none:

[image]

I also have an *.editorconfig* file and *tslint.json* files. The *tslint.json* file has trailing commas set to false. Lastly, I am using the Prettier Formatter for VSCode extension. Anyway, the trailing commas still appear unless I put this in package.json:

```
"prettier": {
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "none"
 }
```

How come if my preferences are set in VSCode settings that I then have to add this snippet of redundant code in the *package.json* file?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to set `"trailing-comma": true` in *tslint.json*. Anyway good practice is to install https://github.com/prettier/tslint-config-prettier so you don't get conflicts.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. trailing-comma is set to false in tslint.json. But I am using the Prettier formatter for VSCode, not the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Is your default formatter set to prettier? Or the default `Typescript and Javascript language features?`

You can check this by opening a typescript file and pressing `ctrl + shift + p` (for windows)

and looking for `format document with` and looking which is the default.

Comment: I get this error: Extension 'esbenp.prettier-vscode' is configured as formatter but not available. Select a different default formatter to continue.

Comment: Did you install the prettier extension? You can find it on the left side or press (ctrl + shift + x) and search for Prettier - Code formatter.

Comment: Sorry, I just disabled Prettier. Now I've re-enabled and format document just works -- so i'm assuming it found that file.

Comment: Wait, but it still leaves a trailing comma unless I put that snippet back in package.json.

Comment: I would put the configuration in a `.prettierrc` file not in package.json, and that means you're not using prettier as a formatter, but the default one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220498/discussion-between-ondie-and-fumeng).

Answer (score 1):

Remove "trailing-comma" in yout tslint config.